# JBossTS FileSytemStore cannot access root of object store

Tags: java, transactions, jboss7.x

I'm getting an unusual exception in a QA environment but cannot replicate it in development.

```
Caused by: com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException: ARJUNA012225: FileSystemStore::setupStore - cannot access root of object store: PutObjectStoreDirHere/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.FileSystemStore.<init>(FileSystemStore.java:490)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowingStore.<init>(ShadowingStore.java:622)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowNoFileLockStore.<init>(ShadowNoFileLockStore.java:53)
```

I'm running Tomcat 7 (OpenJDK 1.6) on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.  Spring 3.x/Hibernate4/Infinispan 5.3.0/JbossTS 4.16.6.Final

Full Stacktrace:

```
[acme]: [WARN ] - 2013-Nov-28 04:51:40 -  arjuna:loadAndInstantiateClass(): ARJUNA012218: cant create new instance of {0}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.common.ClassloadingUtility.loadAndInstantiateClass(ClassloadingUtility.java:131)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.objectstore.StoreManager.initStore(StoreManager.java:142)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.objectstore.StoreManager.getActionStore(StoreManager.java:103)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.objectstore.StoreManager.getRecoveryStore(StoreManager.java:65)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService.<init>(ActionStatusService.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.common.ClassloadingUtility.loadAndInstantiateClass(ClassloadingUtility.java:137)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.start(TransactionStatusManager.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.<init>(TransactionStatusManager.java:58)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.createTransactionStatusManager(TxControl.java:188)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.<clinit>(TxControl.java:318)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:85)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doJtaBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:865)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:822)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.getTokenForSeries(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException: ARJUNA012225: FileSystemStore::setupStore - cannot access root of object store: PutObjectStoreDirHere/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.FileSystemStore.<init>(FileSystemStore.java:490)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowingStore.<init>(ShadowingStore.java:622)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowNoFileLockStore.<init>(ShadowNoFileLockStore.java:53)
    ... 74 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a permission error.  If you have installed Tomcat 7 package on Ubuntu, check that /var/lib/tomcat7 is owned by tomcat7:tomcat7!!!

For other Linux distributions / Tomcat installation types:

Do:
ps -ef : grep "tomcat"
Find the tomcat processid

pwdx processid
Will output the tomcat process working folder

make sure it has write permissions for the user that tomcat runs as.